# How to find @SuppressFBWarnings annotations that are no longer needed?

Tags: java, spotbugs

I'm working with a [mid-size Java codebase](https://github.com/JMRI/JMRI) that has a lot of `@SuppressFBWarnings` annotations.  A few of them, not all, are no longer needed because code's been made generic, APIs improved, etc.

Is there a way to find out which of those annotations are no longer needed?

I can comment them out and re-run SpotBugs, but it's really tedious to manually identify which are needed and which are not.  So I'm hoping for some SpotBugs option like `+warningToken` for the Eclipse compiler, or perhaps some more imaginative solution.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Sorry, I must not have been clear.  The problem is finding SuppressFBWarnings that _aren't_ needed.  There are over a thousand of them that are needed; commenting out, compiling, checking the results by hand, and updating the source would be a serious amount of time I'd rather not spend if somebody comes up with a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is a way of telling Spotbugs to either ignore all @SuppressFBWarnings annotations or in a specific directory or among a list of files. I don't think Spotbugs has that feature as yet. 
You might be better off using the exclude file filter provided by Spotbugs that prevents a compile-time dependency on the SuppressFBWarnings annotation. It can always be discarded should you wish to check your code to see where and which suppressions have been resolved since.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the IDE in which you are developing, you can search your files using regular expressions.

**For example:**

[@SuppressFBWarnings]

"Entire Solution" (Including External Items)

"*.cs"

With this you can generate a list of all the files and points within them in which is the instruction you want to evaluate or delete.

Comment: Some of the SuppressFBWarnings are needed, some are not.  A search can't tell that.

Comment: I'd suggest that you comment out all the @SuppressFBWarnings and run spotbugs on your codebase once more. The commented suppressions that match the violations are needed; the others aren't.

Comment: PMD has an option that allows suppressed violations to be displayed. That's PMD, however, not Spotbugs. You can examine their codebase to see how they do it. They use the @SuppressWarnings annotation instead.